# Update data in the table using XML string

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I have table which contains columns like

- `SiteID (identity_Col)`
- `SiteName`
- `POrderID`
- `Location`
- `Address`
- `Cluster`
- `VenderName`

I want to use xml string to insert/update/delete data in this table. Apart from this column, XML string contains one more column viz. RowInfo. This column will have values like "Unchanged","Update","New","Delete". Based on this values the rows in the table should be inserted,updated,deleted.

My XML string is as below:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <DataTable>
     <SiteID>2</SiteID>
     <SiteName>NIZAMPURA</SiteName>
     <POrderID>7</POrderID>
     <Location>NIZAMPURA</Location>
     <SiteAddress>Vadodara</SiteAddress>
     <Cluster>002</Cluster>
     <SubVendorName>Test Vender-1</SubVendorName>
     <RowInfo>UNCHANGED</RowInfo>
  </DataTable>
  <DataTable>
     <SiteID>16</SiteID>
     <SiteName>Site-1</SiteName>
     <POrderID>7</POrderID>
     <Location>Alkapuri</Location>
     <SiteAddress>test</SiteAddress>
     <Cluster>Test Cluster</Cluster>
     <SubVendorName>Test Vender12</SubVendorName>
     <RowInfo>UNCHANGED</RowInfo>
  </DataTable>
  <DataTable>
     <SiteID>17</SiteID>
     <SiteName>Site-3</SiteName>
     <POrderID>7</POrderID>
     <Location>Alkapuri123</Location>
     <SiteAddress>test123</SiteAddress>
     <Cluster>Test Cluster123</Cluster>
     <SubVendorName>Test Vender123</SubVendorName>
     <RowInfo>DELETE</RowInfo>
  </DataTable>
</NewDataSet>'
```

This is the code that I have written to insert data in table if RowInfo = "NEW"

```
IF len(ISNULL(@xmlString, '')) > 0
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @docHandle1 int = 0;
    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @docHandle1 OUTPUT, @xmlString

    INSERT INTO [SiteTRS] (
                [SiteName],
                [POrderID],
                [Location],
                [SiteAddress],
                [Cluster],
                [SubVendorName])
    SELECT SiteName,POrderID,Location,SiteAddress,Cluster,SubVendorName
        FROM OPENXML (@docHandle1, '/NewDataSet/DataTable')

        WITH (SiteName varchar(50) './SiteName',
          POrderID varchar(50) './PorderID',
          Location varchar(50) './Location',
          SiteAddress varchar(max) './SiteAddress',
          Cluster varchar(50) './Cluster',
          SubVendorName varchar(50) './SubVendorName',
          RowInfo varchar(30) './RowInfo')   
    WHERE RowInfo='NEW'
```

But I don't know how to use XML to update/delete records in the table. Please guide
I am novice in the XML so dont have any idea. Please forgive me if I am making something childish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would strongly recommend not to use the old, legacy `OPENXML` stuff anymore - with XML support in SQL Server, it's much easier to use the built-in XPath/XQuery methods.

In your case, I would use a CTE (Common Table Expression) to break up the XML into an "inline" table of rows and columns:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<NewDataSet>
  <DataTable>
    <SiteID>2</SiteID>
    <SiteName>NIZAMPURA</SiteName>
    <POrderID>7</POrderID>
    <Location>NIZAMPURA</Location>
    <SiteAddress>Vadodara</SiteAddress>
    <Cluster>002</Cluster>
    <SubVendorName>Vender-1</SubVendorName>
    <RowInfo>UPDATE</RowInfo>
  </DataTable>
  <DataTable>
    <SiteName>Site-1</SiteName>
    <POrderID>7</POrderID>
    <Location>Alkapuri</Location>
    <SiteAddress>test</SiteAddress>
    <Cluster>Cluster-1</Cluster>
    <SubVendorName>Test Vender</SubVendorName>
    <RowInfo>NEW</RowInfo>
  </DataTable>
</NewDataSet>'

;WITH XMLData AS
(
    SELECT
        NDS.DT.value('(SiteID)[1]', 'int') AS 'SiteID',
        NDS.DT.value('(SiteName)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS 'SiteName',
        NDS.DT.value('(POrderID)[1]', 'int') AS 'POrderID',
        NDS.DT.value('(Location)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS 'Location',
        NDS.DT.value('(SiteAddress)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS 'SiteAddress',
        NDS.DT.value('(Cluster)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS 'Cluster',
        NDS.DT.value('(SubVendorName)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS 'SubVendorName',
        NDS.DT.value('(RowInfo)[1]', 'varchar(20)') AS 'RowInfo'
    FROM 
        @input.nodes('/NewDataSet/DataTable') AS NDS(DT)
)
SELECT *
FROM XMLDATA
```

This gives you rows and columns which you can work with.

```
SiteID  SiteName   POrderID Location   SiteAddress  Cluster    SubVendorName   RowInfo
  2     NIZAMPURA     7     NIZAMPURA  Vadodara     002        Vender-1        UPDATE
 NULL   Site-1        7     Alkapuri   test         Cluster-1  Test Vender     NEW
```

Now if you're on SQL Server **2008** or newer, you could combine this with the [**MERGE** command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) to do your `INSERT/UPDATE` in a single statement, basically.

If you're on 2005, you will need to either store this information into a temporary table / table variable inside your stored proc, or you need to do the select multiple times; the CTE allows only one single command to follow it.

**Update:** with this CTE, you can then combine it with a `MERGE`:

```
;WITH XmlData AS 
(
    SELECT
        NDS.DT.value('(SiteID)[1]', 'int') AS 'SiteID',
        NDS.DT.value('(SiteName)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS 'SiteName',
        NDS.DT.value('(POrderID)[1]', 'int') AS 'POrderID',
        NDS.DT.value('(Location)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS 'Location',
        NDS.DT.value('(SiteAddress)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS 'SiteAddress',
        NDS.DT.value('(Cluster)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS 'Cluster',
        NDS.DT.value('(SubVendorName)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS 'SubVendorName',
        NDS.DT.value('(RowInfo)[1]', 'varchar(20)') AS 'RowInfo'
    FROM 
        @input.nodes('/NewDataSet/DataTable') AS NDS(DT)
)
MERGE INTO dbo.SiteTRS t
USING XmlData x ON t.SiteID = x.SiteID
WHEN MATCHED AND x.RowInfo = 'UPDATE'
   THEN 
     UPDATE SET 
        t.SiteName = x.SiteName,
        t.POrderID = x.POrderID,
        t.Location = x.Location,
        t.SiteAddress = x.SiteAddress,
        t.Cluster = x.Cluster,
        t.SubVendorName = x.SubVendorName

WHEN MATCHED AND x.RowInfo = 'DELETE'
   THEN DELETE 

WHEN NOT MATCHED AND x.RowInfo = 'NEW'
   THEN 
      INSERT(SiteID, SiteName, POrderID, Location, SiteAddress, Cluster, SubVendorName)
      VALUES(x.SiteID, x.SiteName, x.POrderID, x.Location, x.SiteAddress, x.Cluster, x.SubVendorName)
;
```

See some more resources:

- [SQL SERVER – 2008 – Introduction to Merge Statement – One Statement for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/28/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-merge-statement-one-statement-for-insert-update-delete/)
- [Using SQL Server 2008's MERGE statement](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/using-sql-server-2008s-merge-statement/194)

Comment: @marc_s..The MERGE command link that you have provided shows only two operations in each block. But I want all three i.e. insert/update/delete. more over it shows insert/update/delete using simple query and not using XML. Can you please elaborate your answer???

Comment: @Chirag Fanse: those are just samples! Of course you can have **many more** conditions to define insert, update, delete and other statements. Browse the web, search on Google - you'll find PLENTY of info! I updated my answer with a rough skeleton of what you need to do...

Comment: @marc_s..What is "NDS.DT.value" in your answer before update? I thought it as alias for '/NewDataSet/DataTable' as you have written "FROM @input.nodes('/NewDataSet/DataTable') AS NDS(DT)" but when I copy ans pasted, it shows error "can not find either the column NDS or user-defined function or aggregate function NDS.DT.VALUE or the name is ambiguous"

Comment: @marc_s..I tried so many things, read your links but still not able to get the idea how to write insert/update/delete command using XMLsting. Can you please provide code based on my data???

Comment: @chirag fanse: updated my answer **yet again** - typed out all the statements as they should be. The **MERGE** statement will do one of those statements for each row, assuming that the `SiteID` is the unique ID that uniquely identifies each of your rows (the primary key). Since it does this for each row in the source table (your CTE based on the XML), it know which row (and thus which `SiteID`) this command is being executed - that's why you can e.g. write just `... THEN DELETE` if a certain condition matches - SQL Server will **know** which row to delete from the source table

Comment: .Thanks dude...It works great, but still problem in deleting record. I have updated XML string of my question. Is not deleted even if it has RowInfo='DELETE'

Comment: @Chirag Fanse: the `DELETE` will only be called if 1) there's a match on the `SiteID` (so are you sure you **have** a row with `SiteID = '17'`, 2) the `RowInfo = 'DELETE'`, and 3) if no other dependencies / foreign key relationships exist

Comment: .Yes, I am sure, I have row with SiteID=17 and RowInfo='DELETE'. What changes should I make in order to make it working..??? By the way again thanks a lot for spending your valuable time...:)

Comment: @Chirag Fanse: can you delete this entry from SQL Server Mgmt Studio by calling:  `DELETE FROM dbo.SiteTRS WHERE SiteID = '17'` ?? If that doesn't work, then `MERGE` also cannot do its work, obviously....

Comment: Yes I can delete it..By the way..I have deleted it using your query with just small correction i.e.                              WHEN MATCHED AND x.RowInfo = 'DELETE'AND t.SiteID=x.SiteID
THEN DELETE

Comment: Hello guys, am using Dataset.getXml() to get the XML data which i can send to SQl, Where 'RowInfo' is not comming, What i can do?